# Two synthetic signals with same frequency result in two different spectrogram results

Tags: signal-analysis, spectrogram, nyquist

I have two signals of the same wave $f(t)=\sin(2\pi\cdot 70\cdot10^6 t ), t \in [0,1e-3] $, which I created with Matlab synthetically.
My first signal has 1e6 samples and the second has 1e5 samples.

1. `syn_signal = sin(2*pi*70e6*linspace(0,1e-3,length(1e6)));`
2. `syn_signal = sin(2*pi*70e6*linspace(0,1e-3,length(1e5)));`

When I measured the spectrogram, signal 1 has 70MHz as expected but signal 2 has 325MHz, how can it happen?
This strange behavior takes place also in Python.

The code for the spectrogram is

```
    win_len = 512;
    samplerate = 1.0737e+09;
    win = hamming(win_len); % use hamming window to prevent spectral leakage
spectrogram(syn_signal, win, win_len -1 , win_len, samplerate, 'yaxis')
```

Comment: Your codes is non-sensical: Both of your signals have a length of 1 since `length(1e6)` is 1 and so is `length(1e5)`. You probably want  something like `syn_signal = sin(2*pi*70e6*linspace(0,1e-3,1e6));` but than you end with different sample rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're actually synthesizing your signals as Hilmar pointed out in the comments:

```matlab
syn_signal = sin(2*pi*70e6*linspace(0,1e-3,1e6));
syn_signal = sin(2*pi*70e6*linspace(0,1e-3,1e5));
```

**There are two issues:**

1. The sample rate is **different** for the first signal and the second:

```matlab
t1 = linspace(0, 1e-3, 1e6); % sample_rate = 1/(t1(2)-t1(1))
t2 = linspace(0, 1e-3, 1e5); % sample_rate = 1/(t2(2)-t2(1)) different
% ...
% ...
% use the correct sampling rate in the call to spectrogram()
spectrogram(syn_signal, win, win_len-1, win_len, sample_rate, 'yaxis')
```

2. **Nyquist** tells you to have a sampling rate greater than twice the highest frequency.
   The sampling rate for your first signal is $\approx1e^9\geq 2\cdot70e^6$ but for your
   second signal it is $\approx 1e^8 \leq 2\cdot 70e^6$, violating Nyquist. As a result, the second signal aliases. You can synthesize signals that work for both sampling rates, such as one with frequency `20e6`, or leave `70e6` but increase the sampling rate for your second signal.